# Error in xy[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r

A little new to learning R, so I'm testing out some codes and trying to learn the plotting function.  Here's what I wrote -

```
library(xts)
library(quantmod)
spy<-getSymbols("SPY",auto.assign=FALSE)
vix<-getSymbols("^VIX",auto.assign=FALSE)
spy_returns<-diff(log(spy$SPY.Adjusted))
vix_returns<-diff(log(vix$VIX.Adjusted))
spy_returns<-na.omit(spy_returns)
vix_returns<-na.omit(vix_returns)
plot.zoo(spy_returns,vix_returns)
```

I'm hoping to just see a scatterplot, but I get an error that says 
`Error in xy[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions`

However the dim of both spx_returns and vix_returns are the same.  So am a little lost.  Would like to find out what's wrong with what I'm trying to achieve.
Thanks.

Comment: What are classes of `spy_returns` and `vix_returns`?

Comment: Your `plot.zoo` statement is probably treating the two arguments as `x` and `y` values.  As these are both `zoo` objects, they are not just simple vectors.  If you want to plot both stocks on the same chart, do the first using `plot` and then add the second using `lines`.